# Pandas - drop overlapping ranges in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Having a dataframe in the following form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                'A': ('foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'),
                'start': (3039, 3536, 9140, 12976, 14982),
                'end': (3536, 4879, 44331, 13641, 15643)
                 })

    A   start   end
0   foo 3039    3536
1   foo 3536    4879
2   foo 9140    44331
3   foo 12976   13641
4   foo 14982   15643
```

how can I drop all rows for which their "range", determined by the `start` and `end` column, overlaps with that from other row? In the example above, rows with index `3` and `4` would be dropped because they are contained within row index `2`.

I tried starting with `shift()` to tentatively create a masking series, but besides not working because all values are `False`, it would only compare to the previous row, whereas I'd like to compare all rows ranges.

```
ranges_mask = ((df['start'] > df['start'].shift(-1)) & (df['end'] < df['end'].shift(-1)))
```

Comment: what should we do if for example end of 3 is greater than end of 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution 
where we only contemplate the case where there are intervals completely within another:

```
df2=df.copy()
groups=pd.Series([1]*len(df))
while (groups.value_counts()>1).any():
    groups=( df2['start'].gt(df2['start'].shift())  &
             df2['end'].gt(df2['end'].shift()) ).cumsum()
    print(groups)
    df2=df2.groupby(groups,as_index=False).first()

print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
dtype: int64
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    2
dtype: int64
0    0
1    1
2    2
dtype: int64
     A  start    end
0  foo   3039   3536
1  foo   3536   4879
2  foo   9140  44331
```

Comment: Does the dataframe needs to be sorted by `start` for this solution to work?

Comment: OK, just figured the original dataframe must be sorted for this to work. A simple `.sort_values('start').reset_index(drop=True)` should do.

Comment: In the case that they are messy and you want to apply it sorted by start then if it is necessary to order. I'm glad to help you:)